# Cannot open PivotTable source file

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, pivot-table

**Answered**

I recorded an Excel macro (and saved it in my personal macro workbook) to create a pivot table and was hoping that I would be able to use it on multiple worksheets. The code works fine when I run it on spreadsheets on my computer, but will not run on other computers or if I try to run it in the VBA editor. It keeps giving the following error: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypmx6.jpg (Cannot find PivotTable source file)

The thing is, the file is saved in that location under the same exact name. I have tried replacing the path with the range of the spreadsheet (which isn't ideal if I want to use it on other spreadsheets), but that produced an application-defined or object-defined error. I have also tried putting it in different locations to no avail.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
   Sheets.Add
   ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "File_Name!R1C1:R1681C105", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

I think the problem is within "File_Name!R1C1:R1681C105" (the path does change if I change the file location, but produces the same error)

How can I get my code to find the source file?

**Answer**: munircontractor's method worked. Had to add the following code just before my code and it was then able to find the source file.

```
Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open("File_Name", , ReadOnly)
```

While it works fine on my computer, I found out that in order for my code to run on other computers, the worksheet cannot be open in Excel, it will only run the macro on a blank worksheet. Could just be a fluke, but wanted to mention it in case anyone else experiences the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but you probably need to open the workbook as an excel application first using `Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(File_Name, , ReadOnly)`... at least that's how is used to reference ranges outside the active workbook.

Comment: It looks like you're using R1C1 notation, however that's not very common for most users. If you change this setting, does it resolve your issue? http://ccm.net/faq/15308-excel-switch-to-r1c1-reference-style

Comment: Thank you so much, munircontractor! You are a life saver! It finally worked!